# how to sort dictionary within a dictionary python

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary, lambda, ordereddictionary

So I've been stuck for a full hour now. I've seen other posts regarding this same issue and I cannot get mine to work.

Here's the dictionary within dictionary I'm trying to sort:

```
diction = {'z': {'golf': 3, 'bowling': 9}, 'a': {'fed': 5, 'alvin': 10}, 'r': {'yell': 7, 'shout': 11}}
```

I'm trying to first sort the outermost of the dictionary, so that's where t[0] comes in. Then I would like to sort the elements that get paired with the letter alphabetically. The desired output --

```
{a:{alvin:10, fed:5}, r:{shout:11, yell:7}, z:{bowling:9, golf:3}}
```

Here's my code:

```
import collections
diction = {'z': {'golf': 3, 'bowling': 9}, 'a': {'fed': 5, 'alvin': 10}, 'r': {'yell': 7, 'shout': 11}}
a= collections.OrderedDict(sorted(diction.items(),key=lambda  t:t[0][1]))
```

This obviously isn't working.

**EDIT**:

So as of now, this is only sorting by letter. I'm getting:

```
{a: {fed:5, alvin:10}, r:{yell:7, shout:11}, z:{golf:3, bowling:9}}
```

What I would like for it to show:

```
{a:{alvin:10, fed:5}, r:{shout:11, yell:7}, z:{bowling:9, golf:3}}
```

Comment: Can you describe the "obvious" problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your inner dictionaries are not `OrderedDict` so they will not maintain their order:

```
from collections import OrderedDict
diction ={'z': {'golf': 3, 'bowling': 9}, 'a': {'fed': 5, 'alvin': 10}, 'r': {'yell': 7, 'shout': 11}}
a = OrderedDict(sorted(diction.items()))
for key, subdict in a.items():
    a[key] = OrderedDict(sorted(subdict.items()))
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a `dict` whose values are `dict`s.

Turning that outer object into an `OrderedDict` doesn't change the inner ones. You have to change them too.

And of course you need to sort each one of them; a single `sorted` call can't work on both levels at once.

So:

```
sorted_items = ((innerkey, sorted(innerdict.items(), key=lambda t: t[0]))
                for innerkey, innerdict in diction.items())
a = collections.OrderedDict(sorted(sorted_items, key=lambda t: t[0]))
```